# easy way to cleanly dump contents of associative array in bash?

Tags: bash, associative-array, zsh

In `zsh` I can easily dump the contents of an associative array with a single command:

```
zsh% typeset -A foo
zsh% foo=(a 1 b 2)
zsh% typeset foo
foo=(a 1 b 2 )
```

However despite searching high and low, the best I could find was `declare -p`, whose output contains `declare -A`:

```
bash$ typeset -A foo
bash$ foo=([a]=1 [b]=2)
bash$ declare -p foo
declare -A foo='([a]="1" [b]="2" )'
```

Is there a clean way to obtain something like the `zsh` output (ideally `foo=(a 1 b 2 )` or `foo='([a]="1" [b]="2" )'`), preferably without resorting to string manipulation?

Comment: By *dump the contents*, do you mean to print exactly `foo=(a 1 b 2 )`, or simply print the pairs(key, value) from the container?

Comment: Why is the output containing the declare command a problem?

Comment: @Rubens: added clarification to the question.

Comment: @glennjackman: it's not a huge problem, but the `declare -A` is redundant and just ends up cluttering the debug output since I already know it's an associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no way to do this other than string manipulation.  But at least we can avoid forking a `sed` process each time, e.g.:

```
dump_assoc_arrays () {
    for var in "$@"; do
        read debug < <(declare -p $var)
        echo "${debug#declare -A }"
    done
}
```

Comment: tried `dump_assoc_arrays $terminfo` but I'm guessing it contains nested assoc arrays, is there a way to make this function recursive?

Comment: `dump_assoc_arrays $terminfo` will expand `$terminfo` first, so would only make sense if `$terminfo` contains the *names* of associative array variables to dump. Is that really what you meant?  Also AFAIK there is no such thing as nested associative arrays in bash.

Answer (score -1):

> the `declare -A` is redundant

Good sir, the `declare -A` is not redundant.

```
$ foo=([a]="1" [b]="2")

$ echo ${foo[a]}
2

$ declare -A bar=([a]="1" [b]="2")

$ echo ${bar[a]}
1
```

Comment: Steven, sorry but you are totally missing the point of the context of the question.  I am debugging my own code, so I already know that `foo` is an associative array.  Therefore the appearance of `declare -A` **in the debug output** is totally redundant and just clutters the output.  So yes, I *can* toss out "essential" information, and I already said I preferred a "native" solution over string manipulation.  That said, it looks like string manipulation is probably the only way to do it :(